# Ionic ReactJS-Redux does not re-render after dispatch()

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, redux

I'm using Ionic with ReacJS and Redux and I have a problem where the elements are **not re-rendered** after the first load, even though the **state changes**.

Here is the code

```
var categoriesTemplate = [{name:'Science', selected:false}, ... ]

const categories = useSelector((state: any) => {
    console.log("Updating State")
    let cat = state.categories
    for (let c of cat) {
      for (var category of categoriesTemplate) {
        if (category.name === c) {
          category.selected = true
        }
      }
    }
    return categoriesTemplate
  })



  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const toggleCategory = (categorySelected: string) => {
    console.log("Toggle + Dispatch")
    for (var category of categories) {
      if (category.name === categorySelected) {
        category.selected = !category.selected
      }
    }

    let newCategories = categories.filter(c => { return c.selected }).map(c => c.name)    
    dispatch(setCategoriesState(newCategories))
  }
```

the first run which loads all the `categoriesTemplate` with property `selected` to `false` works fine. 
When I trigger the `toggleCategory()` I see that `category` (fetched from Redux after `dispatch()`) is correctly updated with the new values, but the elements are not re-rendered.

I've logged both the state update and the rendering code which is

```
return (
      // Some React Components
      {
          categories.map(l => {
            console.log("Rendering")
            return ( ... )
        })
     }
     // Some React Components
     )
```

here is the log, as you can see the initialization is rendered correctly (first `"Updating State"` + `"Rendering"`), but after the trigger of `toggleCategory()` the state is updated from Redux `"Updating State"` while the elements are **not** `"Rendering"`

[image]

Am I missing something?

Ps I'm not posting code from reducer and action because it works, since the updated value reaches my `category` state, and didn't want to add entropy, but if you need I can post it.

Comment: Your selector always returns categoriesTemplate and mutates it. React doesn't see that it has changed so won't re render.

Comment: so if I'd return/create a new object each time instead of categoriesTemplate, would that trigger the rendering? Or is it a design problem?

Comment: Yes, the selector needs to return a new array but even then you are still mutating individual items of the array and that will cause items to not re render if they're pure. I'll add an example with a stateful component.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using local state and reselect to memoize the categories with selected property.

```js
const { createSelector } = Reselect;

const categoriesTemplate = [
  { name: 'Science', selected: false },
  { name: 'Technology', selected: false },
];
//selectors
const selectCategoriesWithSelected = createSelector(
  [
    (allCategories) => allCategories,
    (_, selectedNames) => selectedNames,
  ],
  (allCategories, selectedNames) =>
    allCategories.map((category) => ({
      ...category,
      selected: selectedNames.includes(category.name),
    }))
);
//Category is a pure component, does not realy matter in this case
//  all category items are re created when you toggle one
//  selected, that's just the way you implemented it and can be
//  implemented better
const Cateory = React.memo(function Category({
  toggleCategory,
  category,
}) {
  return (
    <li>
      <a
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          toggleCategory(category.name);
        }}
        href="/"
      >
        {category.name}{' '}
        {category.selected ? 'selected' : ''}
      </a>
    </li>
  );
});
function App() {
  const [
    selectedCategoriesNames,
    setSelectedCategoriesNames,
  ] = React.useState(() =>
    categoriesTemplate
      .filter(({ selected }) => selected)
      .map(({ name }) => name)
  );
  const toggleCategory = React.useCallback(
    (categoryName) =>
      //this is the action and reducer combined because
      //  we are using local state
      setSelectedCategoriesNames(//add or remove category name to selected list
        (selectedCategoriesNames) =>
          selectedCategoriesNames.includes(categoryName)
            ? selectedCategoriesNames.filter(
                (c) => c !== categoryName
              )
            : selectedCategoriesNames.concat(categoryName)
      ),
    []
  );
  const categoriesWithSelected = selectCategoriesWithSelected(
    categoriesTemplate,
    selectedCategoriesNames
  );
  return (
    <ul>
      {categoriesWithSelected.map((category) => (
        <Cateory
          key={category.name}
          category={category}
          toggleCategory={toggleCategory}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reselect/4.0.0/reselect.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

If you just put categoriesTemplate in state and change selected it would be both simpler and can be optimized:

```js
const Cateory = React.memo(function Category({
  toggleCategory,
  category,
}) {
  console.log('rendering', category.name);
  return (
    <li>
      <a
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          toggleCategory(category.name);
        }}
        href="/"
      >
        {category.name}{' '}
        {category.selected ? 'selected' : ''}
      </a>
    </li>
  );
});
function App() {
  const [categories, setCategories] = React.useState([
    { name: 'Science', selected: false },
    { name: 'Technology', selected: false },
  ]);
  const toggleCategory = React.useCallback(
    (categoryName) =>
      //this is the action and reducer combined because
      //  we are using local state
      setCategories((categories) =>
        categories.map((c) =>
          c.name === categoryName
            ? { ...c, selected: !c.selected }
            : c
        )
      ),
    []
  );
  return (
    <ul>
      {categories.map((category) => (
        <Cateory
          key={category.name}
          category={category}
          toggleCategory={toggleCategory}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reselect/4.0.0/reselect.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```